# Optim function: consider negative values, but avoid zero

Tags: r, optimization

Is there any way how to consider negative values, but avoid zero in optim function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean.

You could square the outcome of your function. Then negatives would become positives and "would be considered"

If you want it to minimize negative scores further down, you could add a penalty for 0, `if( score == 0 ) return(Inf)`

Or some other value if you want it to be less brutal.